# How do I get my socket code to send more than one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, server

I am trying to create a socket server connection that sends manual input commands to the client.

I can send 1 command/line to it, but I am unable to get input() to prompt me for the second command and then send it. I can do it once, but not twice or more.

I tried giving it an if statement and another while loop. Neither produced the desired results.

```
import socket
import time

inputdata = input("Enter command: ")
test_data =  bytes(inputdata, encoding='utf-8')
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('localhost', 667))
s.listen()
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    if(test_data):
            c.send(test_data)
    time.sleep(.1)
```

If I put input() inside the loop, my code just hangs.

```
import socket
import time

inputdata = 0
#test_data =  bytes(inputdata)
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('localhost', 667))
s.listen()
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    inputdata = input("Enter command: ")
    test_data =  bytes(inputdata)
    if(test_data):
            c.send(test_data)
    time.sleep(.1)
```

How do I get my code to send more than 1 input() command/line to the client?

Comment: Put the prompt for information inside the loop. Why isn't this obvious?

Comment: BTW, TCP sockets don't have message boundaries. There's no way for the client to know where one command ends and the next one begins. You need to implement an application protocol to add this information.

Comment: @mkrieger1 If I place input() inside the loop, I can't even to get it to properly prompt me even once.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`accept()` shouldn't be in the loop, since it waits for another connection from the client.

```
import socket
import time

inputdata = 0
#test_data =  bytes(inputdata)
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('localhost', 667))
s.listen()
c, addr = s.accept()
while True:
    inputdata = input("Enter command: ")
    test_data =  bytes(inputdata)
    if(test_data):
        c.send(test_data)
    time.sleep(.1)
```